# How to get a filename list with ncftp?

Tags: bash, shell, ncftp

So I tried

```
ncftpls -l
```

which gives me a list

```
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup      3817084 Jan 29 15:50 1548773401.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup      3817089 Jan 29 15:51 1548773461.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup      3817083 Jan 29 15:52 1548773521.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup      3817085 Jan 29 15:53 1548773582.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup      3817090 Jan 29 15:54 1548773642.tar.gz
```

But all I want is to check the timestamp (which is the name of the tar.gz)
How to only get the timestamp list ?

As requested, all I wanted to do is delete old backups, **so awk was a good idea (at least it was effective) even it wasn't the right params**. My method to delete old backup is probably not the best but it works

```
ncftpls *authParams* | (awk '{match($9,/^[0-9]+/, a)}{ print a[0] }') | while read fileCreationDate; do
    VALIDITY_LIMIT="$((`date +%s`-600))"
    a=$VALIDITY_LIMIT
    b=$fileCreationDate
    if [ $b -lt $a ];then
        deleteFtpFile $b
    fi
done;
```

Comment: I think this is related to bash programming .. Just saying for the one who really wants to have this question closed

Comment: sure, see edit , need anything more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to only display the timestamps from the output like so:

```
ncftpls -l | awk '{ print $5 }'
```